# How does a one-down frame, and a down frame work?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have been reading **one-down frames** and the **down frames**, I am a little but confused as in :-

a) What are they?
b) How does progress know what frame to allocate?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You might want to limit your tags to "progress-4gl", "progress-db" and "openedge".  When people post with plain old "progress" or other generic tags (like "4gl") a whole bunch of people who have no idea what the Progress 4GL (or "ABL") is tend to downvote them out of ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A frame can have "down" iterations.  When the code writing to a down frame iterates the next occurrence of the data is below the previous.  This is great for easily presenting data in tabular form.

Depending on the sort of block the frame is associated with it may automatically be a DOWN frame.  For instance:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

repeat i = 1 to 10:
  display i with no-box.
end.
```

This will result in:

```
         i
──────────
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
        10
```

REPEAT blocks are iterating blocks and the default (unnamed) frame will be a  down frame.  (FOR EACH  blocks are also iterating blocks).

DO blocks are not iterating so the following:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

do i = 1 to 10:
  display i with no-box.
end.
```

results in:

```
         i
──────────
        10
```

If you have a really slow system (or a connection via an old-fashioned 1200 baud modem) you might see "1" through "10" overwriting one another in the space that ends up being "10".

To get a DO block to act like the REPEAT block:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

do i = 1 to 10:
  display i with no-box 10 down.
  down.  /* advances a down frame to the next line */
end.
```

The "10 down" means that the frame will reserve room for 10 iterations.  If you omit "10" the frame will use the rest of the space remaining on the screen.

The DOWN statement tells the frame (in this case the default, unnamed frame) to move to the next line.  You could also say "down 2." or "down 5." to insert multiple blank lines.

If you want a frame to iterate but it does not do so automatically you probably need to add "down" to the frame phrase (the syntax that starts with "with") and maybe add an explicit DOWN statement depending on the nature of the loop that you are executing.

Comment: When would you choose down over skip?

When I try 
```display "Hello World" with 2 down.
down.
display "Goodbye World".``` 

The second line doesn't begin at the start. It's moved over so that it's in the same position as if it was still on the first line. When I try 
```display "Hello World." with 2 down.
display skip.
display "Goodbye World.".```

It's working as intended.

Comment: Rather than ask a new question in the comments to an old answer you should create a new question.